# Is there a way to check agent Availability in Microsoft Directline APIs?

Tags: dynamics-crm, direct-line-botframework

We're creating a chatbot and in which we want to add one feature called agent Presence Check, which checks if any agent is available or not and just returns true even if one agent is available and false in opposite case.

Is there any API which checks that?

Eg: When we created slack chatbot there wasn't any API for this either but it returned list of agents in group, with their current status, based on active status we checked if agents are available.

Comment: You might be able to use GraphAPI to do this - retrieve a user's online status. Not sure though